# How would I say "This place is Heaven on Earth"?

Tags: set-phrases, phrases, english-to-japanese, idioms

How would I say "This place is Heaven on Earth"? Would

> このところは地球上の天国です。

be correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say...

> ここは[地上]{ちじょう}の[楽園]{らくえん} だ/です。

---

「このところ」 means "recently" "lately" "these days".

Comment: 全く同じ和訳が、研究社英和中辞典に 　https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/This+is+a+heaven+on+earth.

Comment: A garden of optimism, interesting perspective.

Comment: maybe a difference of heaven and paradise

Comment: 小学館プログレッシブ英和も「a heaven on earth」を「地上の楽園」って訳してるんですね　https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/a+heaven+on+earth/

Answer (score 1):

じゃあ、私は中国の説話{せつわ}が好きなので、

> この場所は[桃源郷{とうげんきょう}](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%A1%83%E6%BA%90%E9%83%B7-580116)だ/です。

Comment: This is what immediately came to my mind as well.

Comment: It seems 地上の楽園 is a definite translation in the dictionaries though.